# Google sheet query error: "Result too large". How to fix?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I am using a `query` function with `importrange` and just recently got back error "Result Too Large". The data im importing from the original sheet has more than 10500 rows of data.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("sheet_name", "Social media posts!A:AS"),"SELECT Col1, Col43, Col23, Col16, Col12, Col44, Col45, Col2, Col3 WHERE Col2='instagram'", 1)
```

Comment: try splitting it into batches and using `IF` instead of `QUERY` that could work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can suggest 2 possible workarounds.

**Split the importrange into two parts:**

```
={QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url/id", "Social media posts!A:AS5000"),"SELECT Col1, Col43, Col23, Col16, Col12, Col44, Col45, Col2, Col3 WHERE Col2='instagram'", 1);
QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url/id", "Social media posts!A5001:AS"),"SELECT Col1, Col43, Col23, Col16, Col12, Col44, Col45, Col2, Col3 WHERE Col2='instagram'", 1)}
```

**Split the query into two parts:**

```
={QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url/id", "Social media posts!A:AS"),"SELECT Col1, Col43, Col23, Col16 WHERE Col2='instagram'", 1),
QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("url/id", "Social media posts!A:AS"),"SELECT Col12, Col44, Col45, Col2, Col3 WHERE Col2='instagram'", 1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me with 50k lines and 14 columns it works by splitting and importing by 5 columns, adding 6th column results in error. I suggest using:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("url/id", "Social media posts!A:E"),
IMPORTRANGE("url/id", "Social media posts!F:J"),
IMPORTRANGE("url/id", "Social media posts!K:O"),
IMPORTRANGE("url/id", "Social media posts!P:T"),
IMPORTRANGE("url/id", "Social media posts!U:Y"),
IMPORTRANGE("url/id", "Social media posts!Z:AD"),
IMPORTRANGE("url/id", "Social media posts!AE:AI"),
IMPORTRANGE("url/id", "Social media posts!AJ:AN"),
IMPORTRANGE("url/id", "Social media posts!AO:AS")
}, "SELECT Col1, Col43, Col23, Col16, Col12, Col44, Col45, Col2, Col3 WHERE Col2='instagram'",1)
```